# Evenly space words except when in multi-word phrases (like 'human rights')

Tags: css

How can I evenly space (ie. fully justify) words to fill a line except when in multi-word phrases (like 'human rights') to create an effect like the below?

[image: activism human rights etc]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use an html list for a nav menu:

tutorial here but many other if you google them:
http://jamesowers.co.uk/css-tutorials/50/horizontal-css-list-menu/

reasons behind it:

- your menu will look good if css does not load / not supported
- helps accessibility
- semantically, you are displaying a list of items - so what's better than a list to display them?

EDIT

the easiest, html/css only, solution is to use a table, however my eyes burn at the sight of a table used for layout. (Depending on the browser support you want to offer, you may get away with `ul li` or nested `div` tags and css `display:table-cell/table-row` etc)

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nTM3S/

```
    <table cellpadding="3" class="myTable" style="text-align:center">
        <tr>
           <td>Politics</td>
           <td>Environment</td>
           <td>Economics</td>
           <td>Culture</td>
           <td>Human Rights</td>
           <td>Politics</td>
           <td>Environment</td>
           <td>Economics</td>
           <td>Culture</td>
           <td>Human Rights</td>

        </tr>
    </table>
```

and css:

```
td {
    width: 1%;
    padding: 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: #900;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put you items into an `<ul>` and add margins to each `<li>`

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/L8qnh/3/

**Html**

```
<ul>
    <li>Politics</li>
    <li>Enviroment</li>
    <li>Economics</li>
    <li>Human Rights</li>
    <li>Country</li>
</ul>
```

**Css**

```
ul{
    list-type:none;
}

li{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Ah, edited question to clarify that I want to evenly space (ie. fully justify) words to fill a line  - hardcoding `margin-right: 40px;` won't do this.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `text-align: justify;` to the line of text you want evenly spaced, and write multi-word phrases (like 'human rights') thus (adjusting the padding appropriately):

```
<span style="padding-right:3px;">Human</span>rights
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which browsers you want this to work in, the answer to your question may be as simple as putting a `&nbsp;` in the phrases you want to keep together.

`Politics Enviroment Economics Human&nbsp;Rights Country`

And then, justify the whole thing. See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XycGB/).

Unfortunately, this doesn't work on all browsers; it's OK in IE8 and Opera, but Firefox and Chrome do stretch the nbsp just like the other spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a div for each element, and set their display properties to inline... and example would be:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .food{
            padding:5px;
            display:inline;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="food">Hamburger</div>
    <div class="food">Pizza</div>
    <div class="food">Hot Dog </div>
    <div class="food">Chicken</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: forgot to mention the padding, but I think it comes clear that is the property that sets the space between elements! ;-)

Comment: Ah, edited question to clarify that I want to evenly space (ie. fully justify) words to fill a line - hardcoding padding: 5px; won't do this